# How to retrieve the Transaction ID (txhash) for a transaction list in Corda

Tags: corda

How can I retrieve a list of transaction information and their respective id (txhash).

I have a State and retrieve information with Query, but I need the transaction ID (txhash) for each transaction.

Use Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query returns a `StateAndRef` which is as the name implies:

1. Your state.
2. A `StateRef`: Every state is a result of a transaction, but the transaction might have produced multiple states (outputs); so the unique "identity" (or state ref) of a state is the combination of the transaction Id and the index of that state in the list of transaction's outputs (so if your transaction with Id XYZ had 3 outputs, and your state was the second output; the `StateRef` would be `XYZ, 1`).

Anyway, to answer your question; if you have a `StateAndRef myStateAndRef`, then you can get the transaction Id with `myStateAndRef.getRef().getTxhash()`.